# Prove that $\overline {X}+ \overline {Y} \subseteq \overline{X+Y}$

Tags: real-analysis

My attemp:

let $z \in \overline{X}+\overline{Y}$ then $z=x+y, x \in \overline{X}, y \in \overline{Y}$.

Exists two successions $x_n\rightarrow a$ and $y_n \rightarrow b$ then $x_n+y_n\rightarrow x+y\in \overline{X+Y}$. So have I prove the inclusion?

Comment: Yes. You have, since $x_n+y_n\in X+Y$.

Answer (score 1):

In a topological vector space, let $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ and suppose $W$  is an open with $x+y\in W$. Then, there exit open neighborhoods $V_1$ and $V_2$ of $x$ and $y$ respectively such that $V_1 + V_2 \subset W$ by the continuity of the sum. Since $x\in \overline{X}$ and $y\in \overline{Y}\,$,  there are points $x'\in V_1\cap X$ and $y'\in V_2\cap Y$. Therefore,
   $$x'+ y' ∈ (X + Y) \cap (V_1 + V_2) ⊂ (X + T) ∩ W$$
 and thus, $x+y\in\overline{X+Y}$.